# PostgreSQL: Windows creating new instance but can't login using pgAdmin3

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I created new instance for postgesql, but cant login using pgAdmin3

I am using Windows 7 and PostgreSQL 9.5

Here's what i did:

1. Extract postgresql-9.5.0-1-windows-x64-binaries in D drive
2. Open cmd (admin account)
3. create data folder
4. Use initdb command
5. use pg_ctl command to logfile start and stop
6. use pg_ctl register command to register service
7. edit postgresql.conf

   ```
   change port from 5432 to 5433
   listen_addresses = localhost
   listen_addresses = *
   ```
8. edit pg_hba.conf

   ```
   Add IPv4 local connections
   host    all             all     samenet             md5
   ```
9. Start the service
10. Lastly, add Network and local service with full control in Data folder where the new instance created.

------ I did not encounter any problems during this process.

But when I login using pgAdmin3 with postgres account or even admin account, same error occurs.

[image]

[image]

I don't know what I've missed.

Comment: The error message is clear: you are providing a wrong password. The initial password for the `postgres` database superuser is provided by you when you run `initdb`

Comment: i tried i so many times, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the authentication method to trust. So you will be able to login without the password.

```
Add IPv4 local connections
host    all             all     127.0.0.1/32         trust
```

In my case I'm allowing all the localhost users to login without password.

If you use `md5` client will need a password for authentication, if you use `trust` client can login without password.

Comment: Did you try creating a new user with a password?
open `cmd` and go to the bin folder and enter the command `psql -U postgres`.

Then create a new user: `CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'yourpassword'; `

Reset the validity: `ALTER USER username VALID UNTIL 'infinity'; `

Comment: user have been created, but same error when login using pgAdmin3.